# meaning of "see" in "the pastime that sees..."

Tags: word-meaning

This is from [a web page](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3920020/Rock-paper-scissors-SLAP-Group-seven-year-old-boys-play-painful-version-age-old-game-winner-HITS-opponents.html) :

> Rock, paper, scissors is about as docile a game as it gets.
>
> But not for these children in Thailand who enjoy an extreme version of
> the pastime that **sees** the boys slapping each other.

I think the "sees" means "[to be the setting or time of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see)" here.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you very much.

Comment: In the context of your post. **see** could be replaced by **involves**

Comment: @PeterJennings Thank you very much.